# C++: How to count the numbers of unique clients in array and output their spending?

Tags: c++, arrays, text

If I have two arrays, one storing the name of clients, and the other storing the amount they have spent, how can I separately output their individual spending?

For example,

```
Array1:[peter,mary,peter,may,edward]
Array2:[300,400,500,300,400,500]
```

The position of the money spent are corresponding to the names, and each one have spent positive dollars.

I know the size of the arrays, but how can I output their individual spending and calculate the number of clients?

Since the clients may have more than one record in the arrays, I am a bit confused on how to count the numbers and output separately.

Expected:

```
**Spendings:**
peter:600
mary:400
...
... 

**Number of people**:4
```

---

Here's my previous idea (sorry for forgetting to include this in my original question):

```
int Array_amount_store[5]; //For storing each clients' amount
for (int i=0; i<=5; i=i+1)  // Initializing
  Array_amount_store[i]=0;
for (int i=0; i<=5; i=i+1)
 for (int j=0; j<=5; j=j+1)
   if (Array1[j]==Array1[i])
      Array_amount_store[i]=Array_amount_store[i]+Array2[i];
```

I just calculated the total amount but am stuck on how to output it.

Comment: Sorry forgot to add my work, gonna edit the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). Use the client names as its `key`, and their monetary sums as its `value`.  Then you can simply loop through the arrays adding up the purchases for each name, and then when finished, loop through the map to output the results.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

std::map<std::string, double> ClientSpending;

for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfArrayElements; ++i)
    ClientSpending[Array1[i]] += Array2[i];

std::cout << "Spendings:" << std::endl;
for (auto &client : ClientSpending)
    std::cout << client.first << ":" << std::put_money(client.second) << std::endl; 

std::cout << std::endl;

std::cout << "Number of people:" << ClientSpending.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have stuck on the unique output problem for couple of days already, thanks for the help.